# In a column, how can I recode data that is in a sequence?

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

In my data-frame, I have a column named "Colors". The data in the Colors column looks like this:

```
Red001.jpeg
Red002.jpeg
Red003.jpeg
Red004.jpeg
... you get the pattern...
Red999.jpeg

Blue001.jpeg
...
Blue999.jpeg

Green001.jpeg
...
Green999.jpeg

Yellow001.jpeg
...
Yellow999.jpeg
```

I want to change `Red001.jpeg` through `Red999.jpeg` into `Red`. Likewise, I need to do this with `Blue`, `Green` and `Yellow` as well. How can I automate this process?

Answer (score 3):

A simple regex will do it.

```
sub("(^[[:alpha:]]+)[[:digit:]]*.*", "\\1", color)
# [1] "Red"    "Red"    "Red"    "Red"    "Red"    "Blue"  
# [7] "Blue"   "Green"  "Green"  "Yellow" "Yellow"
```

**Data.**

```
color <- scan(what = character(), text = "
Red001(dot)jpeg
Red002(dot)jpeg
Red003(dot)jpeg
Red004(dot)jpeg
Red999(dot)jpeg
Blue001(dot)jpeg
Blue999(dot)jpeg
Green001(dot)jpeg
Green999(dot)jpeg
Yellow001(dot)jpeg
Yellow999(dot)jpeg
")
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use the regular expression.

```
dat$V1 <- sub("[0-9]{3}\\.jpeg$", "", dat$V1)
```

**Data**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Red001.jpeg
Red002.jpeg
                  Red003.jpeg
                  Red004.jpeg
                  Red999.jpeg
                  Blue001.jpeg
                  Blue999.jpeg
                  Green001.jpeg
                  Green999.jpeg
                  Yellow001.jpeg
                  Yellow999.jpeg",
                  header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like pattern is `[colour][3 digits][dot][jpeg]`. Then we can use *substring* without regex:

```
substring(dat$V1, first = 1, last = nchar(dat$V1) - 8)

# [1] "Red"    "Red"    "Red"    "Red"    "Red"    "Blue"   "Blue"   "Green" 
# [9] "Green"  "Yellow" "Yellow"
```

Or fun solution, looks like each colour is repeated 999 times:

```
rep(c("Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow"), rep(999, 4))
```